# Cannot create replicaset in MongoDB using rs.add or rs.initiate(configObject)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have tried creating a replica set while logged into a mongo shell using the following commands:

```
var replConfig = {
    _id:"repl_dal",
    version: 1,
    members:[
        {
            _id:1,
            host:'127.0.0.1:27018',
            priority: 10
        },
        {
            _id:2,
            host:'127.0.0.1:27019',
        },
        {
            _id:3,
            host:'127.0.0.1:27020',
            arbiterOnly: true
        }
    ]
}

rs.initiate(replConfig)
```

I also tried this:

```
rs.add('host:127.0.0.1:27017')
```

It threw an error:
Error: assert failed : no config object retrievable from local.system.replset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also update each members priority and votes in a replica set using the `reconfig()` function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/

Also make sure that your `mongod.conf` file lists all your host names and that you configured it to support a replica set https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/